# Get the first 20 records from the table in magento

Tags: php, magento

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using Magento CE 1.7.0.2

```
$_PCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->setVisibility(array(2,3,4))                   
                    ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
```

i did like this its working fine but i want only first 20 products.

So how can i do that one ?

Any Ideas ?

Comment: I want to get first 20 records from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

you may need to use `->setPageSize(20);`

```
$_PCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->setVisibility(array(2,3,4))                   
                ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
                ->setPageSize(20)
                >setCurPage(1);
```

or you can use this also

```
$_PCollection->getSelect()->limit(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
 ->setPage(1, 20)
```